# Read CSV for variable and check the cells on that line for another variable

Tags: batch-file, csv

I am trying to create a batch file to read a CSV file to find a username that will be a variable then check the next 10 cells on that line if they match another variable which will be a number.

Example CSV:

```
bsmith, 22, 14, 15, 12, 18, 19
cwright, 10, 15, 11, 2
hwrong, 2, 6, 3
csmith, 10, 16, 19, 3, 5, 19, 18, 7, 2, 4
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

I have this to find the username but now I want to check the numbers if they match another variable:

Variables are: 'username' and 'sitenum'

```
findstr /c:"%username%" "ACL.csv" >nul 2>&1
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
echo AUTHORIZED
) else (
echo UNATHORIZED!!!!
)
```

Comment: Is this a Windows batch file? Your tag implies Linux-like systems, but `findstr` is a Windows command.

Comment: Yes it is windows. my apologies, I am new to superuser
Updated tags

Comment: @JimBean2208 If you use the limited regular expression options of the `FINDSTR` command you should be able to do it with one `FINDSTR`. `findstr /r /c:"%username%,.* %sitenum%," "ACL.csv"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to check the numbers if they match another variable

Just pipe (`|`) the output from the first `findstr` into another `findstr` as follows:

```
findstr /c:"%username%" "ACL.csv" | findstr /c:" %sitenum%," >nul 2>&1
```

Note:

- the leading  (space) and trailing `,` (comma) are important as this prevents 1 matching 11 (for example)

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.

Comment: Actually this will fail when trying to find the last number for each user name because the data example does not have a trailing comma at the end of each line. As will my answer as well.

Comment: You can just change the second `FINDSTR` to `findstr /C:" %sitenum%," /RC:" %sitenum%$"`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the limited regular expression options of the FINDSTR command you should be able to do it with one FINDSTR.

```
findstr /r /c:"%username%,.* %sitenum%," /c:"%username%,.* %sitenum%$" "ACL.csv"
```