# Read file with findstr to determine exact results

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am trying to find an exact number within a file that has similar numbers. For example my file contains:

```
bsmith,45,13,67,,,,,,11,13,
```

I would like to check, for example for the number 1.

This is what I have:

```
findstr /c:"%user%" "ACL.csv" >check
findstr /c:"\<%num%\>" "check
echo %errorlevel%
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
echo AUTHORIZED
) else (
echo UNAUTHORIZED
)
```

I tried this but if the variable num=1 then the result is still true as the file contains 11

```
findstr /c:"%user%" "ACL.csv" >check
findstr /c:"%num%" "check
echo %errorlevel%
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
echo AUTHORIZED
) else (
echo UNAUTHORIZED
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What didn't you like about my answer in your previous question? I am not understanding how this is any different then your previous question. Why did you start another question?

Comment: Is there always a comma after the last number.  If not the code Dave provided to you will fail.

Comment: It is reading from a CSV file. When I was piping the info out to a temp file (check) from the CSV there were commas but from what David provided reading directly from the CSV I tested and it works.
findstr /c:"%user%" "ACL.csv" | findstr /c:",%num%," >nul 2>&1

Comment: Let me rephrase this a bit like a story because I think you are not understanding. In your previous question, your data example had no comma after the last number. `bsmith, 22, 14, 15, 12, 18, 19`.  Your new example does show a comma now being after the last number: `bsmith,45,13,67,,,,,,11,13,`.  Dave's code will only match if there is a comma after the number.  So if your very last column in the data ends with a number and there is no comma after that number because it is the last field, it will not match.

Comment: My mistake, there is no comma after the last number. The commas are the output from reading a line from a CSV file. With Dave's answer there is no piping out of the results of the findstr command to a file then reading it again, his solution reads from the CSV therefore there are no commas.... as least form what I understand. From what I have tested Dave's solution has worked for me. I appreciate everyone's assistance and input.

Comment: What do you mean there are NO commas.  The commas are in your data and the answer provided is matching on commas.  If are trying to match user `bsmith` with the number `13`, it will not match this line: `bsmith,45,13,67,,,,,,11,13` because there is not a comma after 13 at the end of the line. The findstr match is only matching on comma, number, comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### if the variable num=1 then the result is still true as the file contains 11

I explained how to do this in [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1276527/read-csv-for-variable-and-check-the-cells-on-that-line-for-another-variable#) to [your previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1276527/read-csv-for-variable-and-check-the-cells-on-that-line-for-another-variable):

> the leading (space) and trailing , (comma) are important as this prevents 1 matching 11 (for example)

In this particular case you have no leading space, so you need to use:

```
findstr /c:",%num%," check
```

Note:

- This will match `,1,` and not `,11,`
- You don't need a leading `"` (quote) before the filename.

A much simpler solution is to use a pipe (`|`) as I also recommended in my previous answer:

```
findstr /c:"%user%" "ACL.csv" | findstr /c:",%num%," >nul 2>&1
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
echo AUTHORIZED
) else (
echo UNAUTHORIZED
)
```

Then you don't need the temporary file `check`.

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.

Answer (score 0):

findstr supports (some variant) of regular expressions, so you can actually usesomething like

```
findstr /R "\<1\>" file.csv
```

to get what you need.

**Explanation:**

- `/R` enables the regex mode
- `\<` is the beginning of a word
- `1` is your example, use your variable here
- `\>` is the end of a word

You can get more information by running `findstr /?` or [online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to go back to your original code and have it match on whole words.  This would by far be the safest option for making sure you match the correct name and number. I would also make the check for the name case insensitive.

```
findstr /I "\<%user%\>" "ACL.csv" | findstr "\<%num%\>" >nul 2>&1
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo AUTHORIZED
) else (
    echo UNAUTHORIZED
)
```